# Simulate 2D biased random walk in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, physics

In R, how do you simulate a discrete Biased Random Walk in which there is an array of points towards which the agent is attracted?

The answer would preferably include a term to control the diffusivity of the particle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting the code from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/261947.html

You can then add a conditional function looping through your array. If the particle location is within a radius (or a square for the purpose of this example) 
- you can add a second random event, whereupon if this true, the particle gets an additional step in that direction, if false - does not.

```
RW2D<-function(N)  {    i<-0    xdir<-0    ydir<-0    xpos<-vector()   xpos[1]<-xdir    ypos<-vector()    ypos[1]<-ydir    for (i in 1:N-1)



      attraction_points <- my.array <- array(1:24, dim=c(2))



     {
       r<-runif(1)
       if(r<=0.25) {xdir<-xdir+1}
       if(r>0.25 && r<=0.5) {xdir<-xdir-1}
       if(r>0.5 && r<=0.75) {ydir<-ydir +1}
       if(r>0.75) {ydir<-ydir-1}




       for (j in 1:24){
       if ( abs(attraction_points[j,0]-xpos) < 4 ){ 
            if ( abs(attraction_points[j,1]-ypos) < 4 ){
                 if(runif(1)<=0.5) {xdir<-xdir+ 1*sign(attraction_points[j,0]-xpos)}
                 if(runif(1)<=0.5) {ydir<-ydir+ 1*sign(attraction_points[j,1]-ypos)}
            }
     }
}        



        xpos[i+1]<-xdir
        ypos[i+1]<-ydir


     }    return(cbind(xpos,ypos))  } rw<-RW2D(10000)

xmin<-min(rw[,1]) xmax<-max(rw[,1]) ymin<-min(rw[,2]) ymax<-max(rw[,2])

plot(rw[,1],rw[,2],type="l",xlab="x",ylab="y",main="Random Walk Simulation In Two Dimensions",col="green4",xlim=range(xmin:xmax),ylim=range(ymin:ymax))

end<-cbind(rw[10000,1],rw[10000,2]) start<-cbind(0,0)

points(start,pch=4,col="red") points(end,pch=4,col="red")
```

NB I have not run the code myself, but that should illustrate the idea, and you should be able to fix any bugs yoruself.